# Navigate through nested yaml list with liquid

Tags: menu, internationalization, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I've seen a few questions about this topic but none could solve my problem. I want to have a multilingual jekyll site without using any plugin. I have a yaml file with this nested list

```
menu:
  fr:
    home:
      name:"Acceuil"
      url:"/"
    team:
      name:"Équipe"
      url:"/equipe"
  en:
    home:
      name:"Home"
      url:"/home.html"
    team:
      name:"Team"
      url:"/team"
```

I'd like to print a different menu depending on the page *lang* option in the yaml front matter. A minimal exemple would be:

```
---
lang: en
---
<ul>
  {% for item in site.menu.[page.lang] %}
      <li><a href="{{ item[1].url }}">{{ item[1].name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and this should print in raw html

- Home
- Team

But instead my code prints nothing, I just have two bullets with no text. I can't see what I'm doing the wrong way, could you guys help me ?

**Edit:**

Ok, my only problem was just that I didn't put space between the value indicator and the value. Now the problem is solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a whitespace between colons and values in the menu file, according to the YAML specification:

> YAML insists the “:” mapping value indicator be separated from the
>   value by white space.

Also remove the `menu:` key and save the menu in a file called `_data/menu.yml`.

```
fr:
  home:
    name: "Acceuil"
    url: "/"
  team:
    name: "Équipe"
    url: "/equipe"
en:
  home:
    name: "Home"
    url: "/home.html"
  team:
    name: "Team"
    url: "/team"
```

Then you can access that data with `site.data.menu` accessing directly to the `lang` key without a `.` between `menu` and `page.lang`:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in site.data.menu[page.lang] %}
      <li><a href="{{ item[1].url }}">{{ item[1].name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This generates:

```
<ul>

      <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>

      <li><a href="/team">Team</a></li>

</ul>
```

---

- I've used a similar approach in a multilingual site with [nav.yaml](https://github.com/marcanuy/jekyll-skeleton/blob/master/_data/nav.yml) and a [langnav.html](https://github.com/marcanuy/jekyll-skeleton/blob/master/_includes/lang_nav.html) include.

Comment: Thank you, putting blank space between the value indicator and the value solves the problem !